# Attach image from Sharepoint list must send to Email, Ms Teams, Kaizala

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, powerapps, power-automate

Is there a way to attach every person image from Sharepoint list connected with Ms Flow. The flow I trigger will need send a "Welcome on board message" including with the person image and send it to Kaizala, Email & Ms Team.

Comment: You could use Incoming Webhooks to [Post external requests to Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) to send message to Teams.

Comment: What is a "person image"?